# How to return a boolean response for a unique and new entry

Tags: mysql

I am looking for an SQL query to identify if there are any `new` `class`s in my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Features` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_username` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `class` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `new` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

#### Edge cases

Here class 3 has no previously `new=0` entries. So the SQL should return 1.

```
| class | new |
|-------|-----|
|     1 |   0 |
|     2 |   0 |
|     3 |   1 |
```

Here class 2 has already a `new=0`. So the SQL statement should return 0.

```
| class | new |
|-------|-----|
|     1 |   0 |
|     2 |   0 |
|     2 |   1 |
```

Here there are no new classes. So the SQL statement should return 0.

```
| class | new |
|-------|-----|
|     1 |   0 |
|     2 |   0 |
|     3 |   0 |
```

Here all classes are new. So the SQL statement should return 1.

```
| class | new |
|-------|-----|
|     1 |   1 |
|     2 |   1 |
|     3 |   1 |
```

---

This query should run on a single `account_username`.

Comment: How do you know when the class was new and when the class was not? What if Class 2 in your example was 0 five years ago and today a record was added with a 1? If you can add or adjust the table, it would be likely beneficial to you to add a createdat, updatedat, createdby, and updatedby column that get updated as well. Have you tried using any aggregate queries and case when or if then else statements yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to select a boolean value based on whether another query (that determines if there are any new entries in the table based on some `new` flag) selects any rows.

Someone could probably do this in a more optimised way, but it could be achieved by doing this:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN COUNT(y.class) > 0 THEN
               1
           ELSE
               0
       END
FROM (SELECT class
    FROM Features
    WHERE account_username = 'someusername'
    GROUP BY class) y
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT class
        FROM Features
        WHERE new = 0 AND account_username = 'someusername'
        GROUP BY class
    ) x
        ON x.class = y.class
WHERE x.class IS NULL
```

This selects 1 if the inner query selects any rows, otherwise 0. The inner query selects the rows that have a new flag associated with them by performing a left join on all the possible classes and all the classes where the flag is 0 where the `x.class` is null.

To run it on a single `username`, create a stored procedure and parameterise the username column.

Hope this helps!